# Query by array type - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to query my mongoDB collection by type.
 
Suppose I have these two documents of ***hello*** collection:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56684ee0f597654b99d0d636"),
        "name" : "Scrooge",
        "surname" : "McDuck",
        "address" : {
                "road" : "Money Bin",
                "number" : 19
        },
        "hobbies" : [
                "money",
                "food",
                "cooking"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("66684ee0f597654b99d0d636"),
        "name" : "Mickey",
        "surname" : "Mouse",
        "address" : {
                "road" : "Topolinia",
                "number" : 34
        },
        "hobbies" : [
                "minnie",
                "cheese"
        ]
}
```

Now, if I query by array type:

```
db.hello.find({hobbies: {$type: 4 }})
```

I don't have any documents in output. As you can see [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/bson-types/) 4 is the number of array type.

Comment: It is not so obvious but the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/index.html#arrays) is clear: *For documents where `field` is an array, `$type` returns documents in which **at least one array element matches** a type passed to `$type`.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. You can simply do this using the ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) and the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator

```js
db.hello.find({ 'hobbies.0': { '$exists': true } } )
```

Another way to do this is by using aggregation and the [`$isArray`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isArray/#exp._S_isArray) operator available in MongoDB 3.2.  But this is less efficient because [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) does a collection scan.

```js
 db.hello.aggregate([ 
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [
             { $isArray: "$hobbies" }, 
             "$$KEEP", 
             "$$PRUNE" 
        ]
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/type/#examples), you need to use a where clause:

```
db.hello.find( { $where : "Array.isArray(this.hobbies)" } );
```

Comment: No you don't need  `$where`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `where` clause. Refer below syntax:
`db.hello.find( { $where : "Array.isArray(this.hobbies)" } );`

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/type/#arrays

> **Arrays**
>
> When applied to arrays, `$type` matches any inner element that is of the
>   specified type. Without projection this means that the entire array
>   will match if any element has the right type. With projection, the
>   results will include just those elements of the requested type.

When you query on the `hobbies` field, the query will actually try to match the elements *inside* the field because it's an array.
So instead you can do:

```
db.hello.find({ $where: 'Array.isArray(this.hobbies)' });
```

But it won't be very efficient and won't use an index.

Comment: You don't need to drop to `$where`